# clonezilla - restore OS partition image to larger/smaller partition

Tags: cloning, clonezilla, partclone

My old disk has failed. I have made partition images of OS partition and MRB partition instead of disk image. I have a disk but its size is smaller than the OS partition image.

1. Is it possible to restore the OS partition image to smaller partition? Will the OS bootable? How about restoring to larger partition?
2. Do I also need to restore the MBR partition too?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118370/restoring-a-big-partition-to-a-smaller-partition-with-clonezilla is an article you want, see more related posts at your right.